# DMARC "policy_evaluated" is "fail" for SPF, even when SPF domain alignment is "relaxed"?

Tags: email, spf, dmarc

A DMARC aggregate report which I received reads (irrelevant pieces removed, domains changed):

```
 <record>
    <row>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition> 
        <dkim>pass</dkim> 
        <spf>fail</spf> 
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mail-provider.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>subdomain.mail-provider.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

I do not understand why evaluated DMARC policy is `fail` with respect to SPF. As `<auth_results>` show, SPF by itself validates. AFAIK, in this case the DMARC failure can be only caused by [passed SPF identity not being identity-aligned according to DMARC policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/171341/50647). But how could it happen in my case?

The DMARC RFC 7489 [reads](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#page-8):

> Identifier Alignment:  When the domain in the RFC5322.From address
> matches a domain validated by SPF or DKIM (or both), it has
> Identifier Alignment.

- Domain in the "From:" field is `mycompany.com`.
- SPF record for `mycompany.com` is `include:mail-provider.com`.
- SPF record for `mail-provider.com` contains a range of IP addresses they use to send mail from. The mail has arrived from an address in that range.
- DMARC policy for `mycompany.com` does not require "strict" alignment for SPF.

I thought that the "passed SPF identity" in this case is `mail-provider.com`, for DMARC to pass it needs to align with `subdomain.mail-provider.com`, and it does so in "relaxed" mode. What am I missing?

Comment: Test your configuration using https://www.mail-tester.com/ and post the results here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Relaxed* in DMARC doesn't mean completely liberated, but has limitations.

From [RFC 7489, 3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-3.1.2) *SPF-Authenticated Identifiers* (emphasis is mine):

> In relaxed mode, the [SPF]-authenticated domain and RFC5322.`From`
> domain must have the **same Organizational Domain**.  In strict mode,
> only an exact DNS domain match is considered to produce Identifier
> Alignment.

The algorithm to determine the Organizational Domain is specified in [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-3.2), but basically the Organizational Domain is just your domain (including TLD) e.g. `example.com` is the Organizational domain for all `a.b.c.d.example.com`.

> Thus, since `com` is an IANA-registered TLD, a subject domain of
> `a.b.c.d.example.com` would have an Organizational Domain of
> `example.com`. The process of determining a suffix is currently a heuristic one.  No
> list is guaranteed to be accurate or current.

This means that the relaxed alignment for `From: user@example.com` would pass if the *envelope sender* used in SMTP `MAIL FROM` command was something like `newsletter@mail-provider.example.com` as the organizational domain for both is the same, but `example.mail-provider.com` has a different organizational domain and fails.

So, what's the solution?

1. You don't necessarily have to do anything. DMARC passes if either **SPF or DKIM** passes.
2. If you want both to pass, the mail provider has to use your domain or its subdomain as the *envelope sender*. That should be possible, as you already have `include:`d their SPF in your SPF record.

Comment: _the mail provider has to use your domain or its subdomain as the envelope sender._  --- 

This sentence answers my question! I incorrectly assumed that the mail provider *does* use my domain as the envelope sender, because DKIM alignment passes. But DKIM does not check RFC5322.From at all!

Comment: DKIM works on the content level while SPF works on the SMTP protocol level. Therefore, DMARC+SPF checks whether the envelope sender is correctly aligned with the `From:` header while DMARC+DKIM compares the DKIM signature with the `From:` header.